# Spring MVC - jqGrid - passing object from view to controller

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid with Spring MVC. To get the parameter I did following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/approveOperators", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody StatusResponse approveOperators(@RequestParam("operatorId") String operatorId) {

    System.out.print(operatorId);

}
```

But what if I require to pass the object that is selected (selrow) only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what if I require to pass the object that is selected (selrow) only.

You've made false assumptions when asking that question. `jqgrid` is a client side framework. What you have on the client side is a textual serialization of the Object that existed on the server side. There is no real-time relation between that object and its textual representation.

What you can do is send JSON or request parameters (form parameters) that will be converted to that object on the server side. Look into `@RequestBody` and `@ModelAttribute`, which you can use to annotate handler method parameters. Spring will convert the corresponding request body or request parameters into an object and provide that object to your handler method.